# Different interface orientation for UIViewControllers in UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller with a rootviewcontroller with portrait orientation. Then i want to push a second viewcontroller to the stack with landscape orientation. Sadly i found no way to force the app to recheck `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. So the landscape viewcontroller is shown in protrait until the user rotates his device into landscape.

I prepared a test project: https://github.com/buechner/InterfaceOrientationTest

Is it even possible to automatically change the orientation within a navigationcontroller stack?

Answer (score 2):

You can present a `ViewController` within `LandscapeViewController` to forcefully make it `landscape`

Use following line of the code in your `viewDidLoad` of `LandscapeViewController`

```
self.performSelector(#selector(LandscapeViewController.launchLandscapeScreen), withObject: nil, afterDelay:1)
```

add following method in your `LandscapeViewController`

```
func launchLandscapeScreen() -> Void{

    let viewController = UIViewController()
    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed. Interesting hack. If it just would be an immediate change and not after 1 sec. Now the users would see a messed up view before it changes to the intended orientation.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done but you'll have to make UIStoryboardSegue subclass

1. Make a subclass of `UIStoryBoradSegue`  and override `perform()`

   ```
   override func perform() {
   let sourceVC = self.sourceViewController
   let destonationVC =  self.destinationViewController

   sourceVC.navigationController!.presentViewController(destonationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
2. In your NavigationControllerSubclass change `shouldAutoRotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

   ```
   public override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
   return (self.topViewController?.shouldAutorotate())!
   }


   public override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
   return (self.topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations())!
   }
   ```
3. while connecting Segue from viewControllers select your segue subclass

4.add `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods in every class to

```
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

    return true
     }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait // or landscape in case you want orientation to be landscape
    }
```

5. As we're making custom segue, you also need to add back button.

Comment: Thank you Misha. But in the end the viewcontroller is added modally and it is not added to the navigationcontroller stack. So no need for a custom segue. I could simply use a modal one.